Is it safe to move object inside its destructor
I'm 99% sure the answer to my question is 'Yes'. I just want to double check my assumption is right and I want to be sure that there is nothing in the upcoming C++ standards that could change the rules (like destructive move if it is really possible).
So, my case is as following. I have an object of the Request type whose lifetime is managed by std::shared_ptr<Request>. When the object is about to die (i.e. the ref counter is zero and std::shared_ptr is calling the ~Request destructor) I need to check some condition and create another instance of the Request type with exactly the same data. Basically I just need to prolong the subscription.
The cheapest way from my point of view is just to call the move ctor of the Request class:
Request::~Request()
{
  if(condition)
  {
    service.subscribe(std::make_shared<Request>(std::move(*this)));
  }
}

As far as I know all data members of the Request instance in the context of destructor are still alive. They are not destroyed yet. So it has to be safe to move them somewhere, right? Is my assumption in line with the idea of C++ and I'm not doing anything stupid?
Related questions:

Revive object from destructor in C++?


Looks legal to me, but keep in mind that you can no longer inherit from Request with this.

You really wanna make sure condition is false in a moved-from state otherwise you're inviting some trouble here.

This might be an XY problem. If you use a std::shared_ptr why not simply add another fixed owner (maybe in your service) and it will keep the Request alive even if all the other owners relaesed it ?

The only source of weirdness that I could imagine was around std::enable_shared_from_this, but the library designers thought of it, so for most non-pathological code I don't see a problem.

while it looks fine, i think you are better off putting similar logic in the deleter of the shared pointer instead of the destructor of the object itself, your current object is really confusing to use and not inheritable, whereas overriding the deleter of the shared/unique pointer doesn't have this issues, you will then not need to move out of it but just rewire a pointer.

@Cubic You really wanna make sure condition is false in a moved-from state What do you mean ?

@wohlstad why not simply add another fixed owner (maybe in your service) and it will keep the Request alive Like a pool of Requests? I have to track the life time of the Request, as I cannot have more than one alive at the same time. Thus, I do really want to make it destructed when is not needed.

@DmytroOvdiienko I didn't actually mean you to have a pool of requests. You can have only 1 request active at a time, but with multiple owners (this is what's std::shared_ptr is about). If you need only 1 owner you can consider to use std::unique_ptr instead. But anyway I am not sure I understand the context enough so my suggestion might not be relevant.

@Cubic -- after the destructor runs the object doesn't exist; there's nothing sensible that can be done with the members that it used to have. There's no need to do anything with condition.

@DmytroOvdiienko std::make_shared<Request> -- This better not throw an exception.  If it does, your destructor will terminate your app with a std::terminate exception.

You may need to worry about the destructor of "service".  if ~Service() incites any ~Request() calls (eg by clearing the last of the shared_ptr s), then there may be an issue. You may need to ensure all Requests are destroyed before service goes out of scope.

This is almost guaranteed to be a bad idea. 1) There's so many gotchas involved that we have a debate here on how to do things correctly. 2) It is exceedingly surprising for an object to copy itself in its destructor, to the point that it might cause an infinite loop by itself. 3) Whatever problem you're solving seems like a misunderstanding of what object lifetimes should be.

@PeteBecker not after the destructor, but nothing stops you from moving an object before it's destroyed...

@Cubic -- but the question is about moving the object in its destructor.

The lifetime of an object ends when ...if it is of a class type, the destructor call starts... So your formally moving an object that does not exist anymore.

It is certainly surprising code and feels a lot like a workaround for a design issue. Not something I would expect in regular code. If this was a code review I would spent more time on actually understanding WHAT is going on, and the design rather than this fragile bit of code.

@PepijnKramer The life time of the Request is fuzzy. That is why std::shared_ptr is used. When I unsubscribe, there is a chance that my object for some short period of time is still used inside the service, which is totally fine. The issue is that I cannot create one more Request before the previous is destroyed. Otherwise I have to solve the thread synchronization issues. I think it is quite common issue, people just do not realize that they might have a data race. Otherwise they have to provide quite strong synchronization guarantees, which kills the performance.

I am usually quite aware of dataraces, and of calls being made to an object that can also be destructed by other threads.  One possible pattern is to pass a shared_ptr to the object you're calling (like request) to a lambda and let the extend the lifetime of the object for the duration of the call. But I don't know if that would fit into your design somehow.

@AhmedAEK better off putting similar logic in the deleter of the shared pointer That is a good answer. I do not really like an idea of making the deleter a resubscriber, as I believe deleter must delete (or reuse) but not resubscribe. However, IMO your solution in general makes the code better and solves the issue @HolyBlackCat mentioned about impossibility to inherit from Request. So if you add your answer, I would vote for it as well. The my only concern is in order to implement this solution I have to deal with the raw pointers, which I would avoid where possible.

@PepijnKramer pass a shared_ptr to the object you're calling (like request) to a lambda : I'm not sure I understand the idea. Could you make a short snippet?

As said I don't know if this comes close to your use case, but this is what I mean in a minimal code example : https://onlinegdb.com/k3dOu0OLW. (Lambdas can really be used creatively and do a lot of heavy lifting, you sometimes just need to think in a way where you think in functions instead of objects)

@PepijnKramer Got it. That is basically how it works in the real code and that is why the lifetime of the Request is not deterministic when I want to unsubscribe. Stackoverflow wants me to move the discussion to the chat. Looks like the topic is clear and there is nothing to discuss anymore. Thanks you all guys again for help.

You're welcome. Good luck

In the end, the line service.subscribe(std::make_shared<Request>(std::move(*this))); might be legal because:

The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when:
(1.3)
if T is a non-class type, the object is destroyed, or
(1.4)
if T is a class type, the destructor call starts, or
(1.5)
the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within o

I emphazised the relevant line.
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#1.4
Yet, a few lines later:

6 Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways. For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor].

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#6
(Again emphasize is mine)
Following [class.cdtor] link:

For an object with a non-trivial destructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor finishes execution results in undefined behavior.

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.cdtor#1
A contrario, we may understand that other usage are legal (otherwise, as stated by @interjay in comment, destructors would be effectively useless).
From the snippet, its not possible to tell if there are no other issues (see the question comments).

Maybe it is more about when the lifetime of the object ends. Inside the destructor you still can access data members and their life time is not ended yet, because their destructor is not invoked (yet)

Basically I can create a copy of the object instead of move. I just thought moving is more cheaper than copy and inside the destructor I do not need the data members anyway

I agree that there is some contradiction there. Because if an object is embedded in other one, its destructor is called after the embedding one, meaning that the embedded outlives the embedding? Have I missed something?

It's allowed to use an object during its destruction, even if that's outside its "lifetime" (see class.cdtor and basic.life#6). If it wasn't then destructors wouldn't be able to do anything.

Another reading would be that, in some cases 1.4 applies, in other its 1.5 but I don't understand that in the lifetime wording.

@interjay If it wasn't then destructors wouldn't be able to do anything of course... Yet the wording clearly states what is forbidden at the beginning of https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.cdtor but is fuzzy about what is legal: "may be used but only in limited ways". In the end I agree with you and thus will remove my answer or patch it if you would be so kind as letting me reuse your "material"

@Oersted Because if an object is embedded in other one, its destructor is called after the embedding one, meaning that the embedded outlives the embedding? Yes, you get it right

The short answer is Yes. Destruction of the object and freeing of the object memory occurs only after the destructor exits cleanly.
However, I would use an object-local Mutex in the destructor to ensure that the same destructor doesn’t get called twice, if that is allowed by the compiler.  I believe later C++ versions don’t allow concurrent destruction, but some earlier versions did.
Operations inside a destructor should be read-only on the object, to ensure not to violate any access rules set on members prior to the destructor being called.
Copying the object itself should be okay, as long as member functions aren’t called that may violate the read-only rule.

What do you mean by object-local Mutex and concurrent destruction?

Operations inside a destructor should be read-only on the object Well... In the destructor you can do anything except throwing the exceptions. In the destructor all data members are in the valid state

by object-local, it means a Lock that is created within the object for the sole purpose of managing access to it by external callers, such that if two tasks called the same destructor, the first one would lock the Mutex, perform its tasks, and exit. Since the second is already in a call to the destructor, the object won’t be destroyed until the second call returns.
Garbage collection should see the reference count is not zero and wait to remove the instance.

Destructor is never called twice. The only sense to have a lock inside the destructor is to protected the referenced data. The local data instead is safe to read/write without any locks, because in case if other threads still have an access to the object, you cannot delete it. Otherwise you have a critical bug in your app
